# angular-ui datepicker does not allow format dd.MM.yyyy when entered into the input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I think the best way to describe this problem is to steer you to the Plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cRO5UgAyZx5SHJSKrzg7?p=preview

The angular-ui datepicker doesn't like us Europeans! 
Start by selecting a date in the datepicker. Let's say it's the 25th October (at least the day should be greater than 12). You see that the datepick-format has been set to dd.MM.yyyy and this is relfected in the date set in the input field.
Now change the year. This is not shown in the datepicker.
However, if you enter the date in the format MM.dd.yyyy, all is well.

I've added the angular-locale_de-de.js, which seems to be working as can be seen in the spelling of Oktober.
So why can't I enter a date in the European [correct-and-logical-day-before-month] format?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in angular-ui datepicker, not your misusage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use angular directive.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.directive('formatteddate', function ($filter) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                return $filter('date')(viewValue,'dd.MM.yyyy');
            });            
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel'
    };
});
```

And than use it in HTML

```
<input type="text" formatteddate="dt.date" .../>
```

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. If you use the datepicker to choose 25th Oct 2013 and then manually change 2013 to 2014, the date is not changed in the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured this out. The problem lies in the new Date([dateString]) method, which only takes certain values. I have edited ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js starting at line 1148. As you can see, there is a TODO in there by the angular-ui team ;-)

```
  // TODO: reverse from dateFilter string to Date object
  function parseDate(viewValue) {
    if (!viewValue) {
      ngModel.$setValidity('date', true);
      return null;
    } else if (angular.isDate(viewValue)) {
      ngModel.$setValidity('date', true);
      return viewValue;
    } else if (angular.isString(viewValue)) {
      var date = new Date(viewValue);
      if (isNaN(date)) {
//   If the date is inputted in the European dd.mm.yyyy format, it will be invalid
//   This flips the month and the day around
          var dLastPos = dateFormat.lastIndexOf('d');
          var mPos = dateFormat.indexOf('M');
          var dSep, newViewValue;
          if(mPos>dLastPos){
              dSep = dateFormat.substr(mPos-dLastPos,1);
              newViewValue = viewValue.split(dSep);
              if(typeof newViewValue=='object'){
                  newViewValue=newViewValue[1]+dSep+newViewValue[0]+dSep+newViewValue[2];
              }
          }
          date = new Date(newViewValue);
          if (isNaN(date)) {
              ngModel.$setValidity('date', false);
              return undefined;
          } else {
              ngModel.$setValidity('date', true);
              return date;
          }
      } else {
        ngModel.$setValidity('date', true);
        return date;
      }
    } else {
      ngModel.$setValidity('date', false);
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Max's solution above is great for formatting the date. However, as JavaScript cannot create a new Date(31.12.2013) in the format dd.mm.yyyy, the month and the day still have to be flipped for this to work. Once the date has been formatted to allow the creation of a Date object, the datepicker will continue to function normally.